# Ruby When is The Time to Raise Exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If `category` is not found, should I return `false` and so return `true` when the transfer done. Or should I raise exception instead?

I'm still not clear when to raise exception.

```
    def transfer(amount, account)
      category = Category.find_by(name: 'Transfer')

      Account.transaction do
        debit = Debit.new(amount: amount, account: self, category: category)                                                                                   
        debit.save                                                                                                                                        

        credit = Credit.new(amount: amount, account: account, category: category)                                                                              
        credit.save                                                                                                                                       
      end                                                                                                                                                 
    end
```

Comment: You should do whatever is most convenient for your application, there isn't just one answer for this.

Comment: If I had to use a fixed category like that, then I would simply create that category if it doesn't exist at runtime on a particular system with `category = Category.where(name: 'Transfer').first_or_create`

Answer (score 1):

I would offer a counter opinion to the one offered by EJ2105.

In this specific situation (and I'm offering opinion more than any sound advice), I would choose to raise an exception (and maybe kill the program and report a critical error).

The category `"Transfer"` is hard coded in your application. The fact that it can't be found is a serious error that probably reflects a database critical failure, such as a missing migration or a seeding error.

As for handling any `#save` errors, I would probably inform the user that the transaction didn't go through. This seems to be an possible and expected (if not happy) outcome.

Comment: I think the choice should not be decided by how severe the error is, but rather which best suits the purpose. In this case there's probably not much difference either way. Important thing is the error is caught and properly handled.

Comment: @EJ2015 - "Important thing is the error is caught and properly handled", I totally agree. I believe the question of Exception throwing is exactly that. Is an Exception the "proper" way to handle the error? I don't really factor in the fact that an error code or error response could be used instead of an Exception. However, when the application's reasonable expectations are ignored (i.e., a missing method, a missing database table, a core missing core data structure), an Exception might be the suitable way to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that can be easily handled with a conditional:

```
if Category.exists?(name: 'Transfer')
  ##process category
else
  ##handle error
end
```

Your intention is also clear here. So I won't use exception here.

But one place where you do want to raise exceptions is inside your transaction, because transactions rely on exceptions to trigger roll back. So, for example, you don't want to use `#save`. Instead, use `#save!`, which raises exceptions when fails. And you'll want to catch these exceptions because they'll bubble up:

```
begin
  Account.transaction do
    debit = Debit.new(amount: amount, account: self, category: category)                                                                                   
    debit.save!                                                                                                                                        

    credit = Credit.new(amount: amount, account: account, category: category)                                                                              
    credit.save!                                                                                                                                      
  end 
rescue StandardError, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved => e
  ##send error to my email
end
```

And if this is an action that's exposed to users, you'll also want to handle the exceptions so users are shown a proper page and gets the correct error messages.